# Very large bottom margin in a nested ListView in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am creating my first Xamarin forms app, coming from WPF. I run into a undesired auto layout of a `ContentPage` that contains a nested `Listview`. The data in the viewmodel is a collection of `Groups`, where each `Group` contains a collection of `Users`.

The representation of the users of one group is as follows:

[image]

But between the first and the second group there is an enormous gap:
[image]

The XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Margin="4"
              x:Name="lstGroups">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,4">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Start" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                            <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
                                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                                      IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference lstGroups},Path=Selected}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ShortName}"  />
                                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="1" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </Grid>
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Button Text="Terug" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I tried several combinations of `VerticalOptions', but the gap simply refuses to go away!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a nested listview? Its not a good practice to do that!!!

Comment: consider using a Grouped ListView instead - nesting them is strongly discouraged

Answer (score 0):

So, indeed, what was needed was to apply grouping in the `ListView`.
The new xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Margin="4"
              x:Name="lstGroups"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="4,0,20,0" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ShortName}"  />
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Button Text="Terug" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
```

Which leads to the following satisfying result:
[image]

More reading [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/)